# In XAML is there a way to default the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

In XAML (or code) is there a way to default the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged for all bindings?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger is the default for most properties. The only one with different default (that I know of) is Text property on TextBox. And in Silverlight you can't change default for SourceTrigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, the UpdateSourceTrigger has different default values for each control and there is no way of setting something that will control how all the elements set their UpdateSourceTrigger! You can definitely create a attached behavior that can go through a page and change all the values?

```
<Window
     local:DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">

</Window>
```

This can then walk the visual tree and change the UpdateSourceTriggers!

Comment: There is no value in that code snippet without implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this

```
public class BindingEx:Binding
{
    public BindingEx()
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```