# Commit edit of current WPF GUI element in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use a keybinding to call a Save method. But if I am currently in a textbox and changed the value, this is not commited.

The save happens before the textbox commits the changes and the saved data does not contain the changes.

How can I commit the edit mode of the current GUI element?

```
InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SavePartCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control)));


class PartViewModel
{
    public override void ExecuteSaveCommand() 
    {
         //commit the edit mode of current GUI element 

         //do the saving
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Databind Before Saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493/wpf-databind-before-saving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One not so elegant way of doing it is setting the Binding to update immediately on changes and not just when losing the focus

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You would have to do this for every GUI element of your control that can stay in edit mode.

Comment: Yep!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765342/in-xaml-is-there-a-way-to-default-the-updatesourcetrigger-to-propertychanged